# Distinguish between different HTTP Authorization headers

Tags: oauth-2.0, http-headers

I have an Android app where the users can login/signup using their facebook account. When the user logins, it sends

```
Authorization: Bearer oauth2token
```

to the server. Now, I need to support Gmail login/signup too. There is also plan to support JWT tokens in the future.

Whats the recommended method to distinguish between OAuth2 tokens from different identity service providers?